# Global structs not being seen

Tags: c++, mingw

Defined as: Class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_
#define CLASS_H_

#include "Class2.h"    
#include <iostream>

struct Struct1{
};

struct Struct2{
};

class Class1 {
};

#endif
```

Then the other header file, where I use this:

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H_
#define CLASS2_H_

#include "Class.h"

class Class2 {
    public:
        Class2( Struct1* theStruct, Struct2* theStruct2); //Can't find struct definitions
    private:
};

#endif
```

These are in the same directory.  And it isn't seeing those struct definitions!  They look to be in global scope to me.  Can someone explain to me why Class2 can't see them?  The compiler isn't complaining about not finding the header of Class, so it can't be that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the whole code. Have you tried that exact code? Where is `<iostream>` used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What follows is a guess at your complete code. Please post that, then we can help you better.

---

If by any chance your *complete* code looks like the following then you should change it

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_
#define CLASS_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Class2.h"

struct Struct1{
};

struct Struct2{
};

class Class1 {
};

#endif
```

Because the `CLASS_H_` macro will already be defined, in `Class2.h` the other header won't be included another time, and then at that time `Struct1` and `Struct2` would not be known yet. Fix it by using a forward declaration where possible. For example in `Class2.h`:

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H_
#define CLASS2_H_

// no need for that file
// #include "Class.h"

// forward-declarations suffice    
struct Struct1;
struct Struct2;

class Class2 {
    public:
        Class2( Struct1 theStruct, Struct2 theStruct2);
    private:
};

#endif
```

If the other header doesn't need the definition of `Class2` either, then use a forward declaration too, there. The definition is not needed for (i.e a declaration suffices)

- References and Pointers
- Function parameters in function declarations that aren't definitions

It's needed if you want to access a member, want to get the `sizeof` or want to defined a function that has a parameter type of `Class2`, `Struct1` etc by-value.

Comment: You sir, are psychic.  The question is then, if I wanted to store a Class2 in Class, how would I reference it in the header file?

Comment: you will need to include the header then :) But then, you will have to manage to not need the header from that other header then to break the circle :) If it can't break, you will have to use a pointer and allocate the object in the .cpp file with `new`. Try out `shared_ptr` :)